# At which distance a 2D material like graphene is safe from charging impurity of a $\rm SiO_2$ substrate?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, solid-state-physics, material-science, amorphous-solids

$\rm SiO_2$ substrate is widely used for the research of 2D materials but charging impurity of amorphous $\rm SiO_2$ degrades their performance, e.g. reduces the conductivity of graphene.

Inserting something between $\rm SiO_2$ and the 2D material such as a few layers of hBN or gas or molecules reduces this influence. [In this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41928-022-00911-x), they made a sandwiched structure with a ~5 nm-thick multilayer hBN between $\rm SiO_2$ and graphene, and they say it's enough to screen graphene from $\rm SiO_2$.

On the other hand, electrostatic potential extends very far.

What is the minimal distance between the 2D material and the amorphous substrate so that the material is safe from the substrate's influence?

Will inserting other materials will protect it as well?

Comment: You are asking for business sensitive information.